# Reflexive Besov spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I don't know whether the Besov space $B^1_{1,1}$ on a one dimensional torus is reflexive or not? Can someone help me please?

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, reminding us of the meaning of your notation would be helpful. Despite the impression given in many sources, notations are not "global variables" in any reliable way, and it is surely impossible to make it be so. For that matter, there are conflicting traditions... so we cannot say "as usual" reliably. Thus, a quick recap is invariably useful.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that anything with an $L^1$-flavour is not reflexive... 

Comment: @paul: in this case, at least we know that independently of the convention chosen for where the indices $s,p,q$ are going, they are all $1$. (-: 

Comment: Sorry for my careless! I mean $B^{s}_{p,q}$, and in my case $s=p=q=1$.

Comment: Thanks all for spending your time answering my questions.

Answer (score 4):

Like Paul Garrett says, there may be difference in definitions. But if I guess correctly at your definitions, then the answer is **no**, the Besov space $B^1_{1,1}(\mathbb{T})$ is not reflexive.

Reference: Theorem 2, item (iv) of Flett, ["Lipschitz spaces of functions on the circle and the disc"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=313779), J. Math. Anal. Appl. 39 (1972), 125–158. (Remark: the definition/characterisation of the space $\Lambda(\alpha;p,q)$ of the paper can be found on page 134.)

Comment: Thanks Willie for the answer, and I appreciate it. Thanks to Paul and Yemon too for enlightening comments.